# change colour of grid view button

Tags: flutter

This is the output screen

[image]

now I want to click on any of the button the button colour changes to golden and all are remain same and when I gain click on the button the button comes to its normal colour.How to do that?
How can I change the color of the button if one of the gridview items is clicked and then the button changes color? But you can only choose one item. How do I make it?

```dart
  return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/images/frame.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    color: AppColors.purewhite),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Get.to(GenderScreen());
                        },
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                              color: AppColors.textgreen),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(children: [
                        const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                            child: CustomIcon(
                                svgIcon: 'assets/images/fourstep.svg',
                                size: 150)),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                              child: Text('Your Interests', style: logintext),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        FutureBuilder(
                            future:
                                Get.put(APIService(Dio())).getInterest(token),
                            builder:
                                (context, AsyncSnapshot<ListModel> snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.waiting) {}
                                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return Container(
                                      child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
                                }
                              }
                              // return snapshot.data!.statusCode == 400
                              //     ?
                              //     // Container(
                              //     //   alignment: Alignment.center,
                              //     //   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                              //     //   child: Row(
                              //     //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              //     //     children: [
                              //     //
                              //     //       Text("Their is no interests",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),)
                              //     //
                              //     //     ]
                              //     //   ),
                              //     // ):

                              return SingleChildScrollView(
                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                          height: 120,
                                          child: GridView.builder(
                                              itemCount:
                                                  snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                              gridDelegate:
                                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                                                      childAspectRatio: 4 / 2),
                                              itemBuilder:
                                                  (BuildContext context,
                                                      int index) {
                                                Data data =
                                                    snapshot.data!.data![index];
                                                id = data.id.toString();
                                                interest = data.interest.toString();
                                                return InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      setState(() {

                                                      });
                                                    },
                                                      margin: const EdgeInsets
                                                              .symmetric(
                                                          vertical: 10,
                                                          horizontal: 5),
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(

                                                              // ? AppColors.golden
                                                              // : AppColors
                                                              // .purewhite,
                                                          border: Border.all(
                                                              color: AppColors
                                                                  .golden,
                                                              width: 3),
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                              const BorderRadius
                                                                      .all(
                                                                  Radius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          20))),

                                                      padding:
                                                          EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                                      child: Center(
                                                        child: Text(
                                                          data.interest.toString(),
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              fontSize: 25),
                                                        ),

                                                        ),
```

Comment: please elaborate your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can save as a global state the index of the selected button and then change the colors of every button checking it with the saved index.

Comment: can u please explain properly?

Comment: @Jack provide the code of the entire widget and i will able to help you

Comment: I have already provided the full code plzz check!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the chips widget for this use case.

You can check the example [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html) (Flutter docs).

I tried using your code to implement the same you can check it out...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const GreenFrog());
}

enum ExerciseFilter { walking, running, cycling, hiking }

class GreenFrog extends StatefulWidget {
const GreenFrog({super.key});

@override
State<GreenFrog> createState() => _GreenFrogState();
}

class _GreenFrogState extends State<GreenFrog> {
Set<ExerciseFilter> filters = <ExerciseFilter>{};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/images/frame.png'),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill),
                          color: Colors.white),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                                    color: Colors.green),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Column(children: [
                              Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                                  child: Icon(Icons.memory)),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
                                    child: Text('Your Interests',
                                        style:
                                            TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ]),
                            SingleChildScrollView(
                                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 20, horizontal: 10),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                        height: 120,
                                        child: GridView.builder(
                                            itemCount: ExerciseFilter
                                                .values.length,
                                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                            gridDelegate:const 
       SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3,
                                                 childAspectRatio:4 / 2),
                                            itemBuilder:
                                                (BuildContext context,
                                                    int index) {
//                                             Data data =
//                                                 snapshot.data!.data! 
[index];
//                                             id = data.id.toString();
//                                             interest = 
data.interest.toString();
                                              var interest = ExerciseFilter
                                                  .values
                                                  .elementAt(index);
                                              return FilterChip(
                                                label: Text(interest.name),
                                                selected: filters
                                                    .contains(interest),
                                                onSelected:
                                                    (bool selected) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    if (selected) {
                                                      
filters.add(interest);
                                                    } else {
                                                      filters
                                                          
.remove(interest);
                                                    }
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              );
                                            }))))
                          ]))
                ])))));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `index` parameter given in the `itemBuilder` property of the Gridview widget with a global variable index to track the current selected grid.

the code provided above is not showing correctly if you can do that, we would better understand the code

Answer (score 0):

After reviewed your code, Here is code snippet logic for InkWell.

```
return InkWell(
    onTap:(){
        setState((){
            String currentInterest = interestList[index].toString();
            String currentInterestId = interestId[index].toString();
            
            //Check if the current interst is already selected
            if(interItem.contains(currentInterest)){
                interItem.remove(currentInterest);// deselect Interest
                interId.remove(currentInterestId);// deselect InterestId
            }else{
            //Deselect all selected interest and interestId
                interItem.clear();
                interId.clear();
                interItem.add(currentInterest);
                interId.add(currentInterestId);
            }
        });
    },
  child: yourChildWidger() // replace here
);
```

Comment: @Jack, Please try this this is working code.